# The logic behind using seek(0)

Tags: python, csv

I wrote this simple program to iterate through elements in a CSV file. I encountered a problem with iterating over an already iterated reader object. My code is as follows:

```
import csv
list = []

file = open("Reading_CSV.txt")

file_read = csv.reader(file)

print(type(file_read))

for x in file_read:
    n, p, r, = x                                 #unpacking values in x into three vaiables. n, p, r stands for Name, Phone and Role
    print("{}, {}, {}".format(n,p,r))

file.seek(0)        #resetting file pointer

for y in file_read:
    list.append(y)

print(list[0])
    

file.close()
```

I found a solution for this problem and that was using seek() function. With resetting file counter with seek(0), this program runs perfectly. But my question is I am resetting the file counter of 'file', not 'file_read', if I reset file counter of 'file_read' this program does not run through second for loop, but in second for loop I am trying to iterate through 'file_read' which is already assigned values (file_read = csv.reader(file)) at the beginning of the script. Can anyone help me understand the logic behind this?

Comment: *"if I reset file counter of 'file_read' this program does not run"* — How are you "resetting the file counter of 'file_read'" exactly…?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`open` gives back a file-object, which does include a file-handle and a offset (after `open` the offset is `0`). When you perform a read-operation on the file-object, the offset is increased. `seek` is used to modify the offset in the file-object. `csv.reader` doesnt read the file, it creates a wrapper to work on the file-object (well, actually on something-that-is-iterable, which the file-object ist). Therefore, modifying the file-object does affect the reader. You could also call `close` and `open`-again between the loops.